# ERROR: balances.transferKeepAlive -32602: Invalid params: UnknownVersion

Tags: error

I am having this issue of an error when transacting on my custom Setheum substrate Node. `ERROR: balances.transferKeepAlive -32602: Invalid params: UnknownVersion.`. Does it have anything to do with changing my `SS58Prefix` to SOMETHING LIKE `204`? or not, because it seems to still show up even after changing my `SS58Prefix` TO `42`. I have no other idea how this Error is rooted. The repo is dependent on the `polkadot-v0.9.10 substrate branch`, it is here: https://github.com/Setheum-Labs/Setheum.

Steps to replicate:

1. `make build && make run`;
2. send an amount using polkadot.js Apps from ALICE to BOB or any other dev account available;

A similar report is here: https://matrix.to/#/!HzySYSaIhtyWrwiwEV:matrix.org/$163790241319597utjEp:matrix.org?via=matrix.parity.io&via=corepaper.org&via=matrix.org

Answer (score 1):

Yes the issue seems to be that I changed the `SS58Prefix` from the default substrate `42`. And the prefix I used is not registered in the [SS58_Registry](https://github.com/paritytech/ss58-registry).
This means that to use a different/unique custom SS58Prefix, one needs to register it to the [SS58_Registry](https://github.com/paritytech/ss58-registry).

My solution was validated in this [issue](https://github.com/Setheum-Labs/Setheum/issues/823)

Comment: There is a custom prefix where any number can be chosen - it should not be necessary to register in the SS58_Registry. There's a custom constructor here: https://docs.rs/ss58-registry/1.17.0/ss58_registry/struct.Ss58AddressFormat.html#method.custom